# Unable to open ports in Windows Azure VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, virtual-machines, ravendb

I'm trying to install RavenDB in an development VM hosted by Azure.

I decided to use 48625 as HTTPS port and 48626 as TCP Port and specified it in configuration.

[image: RavenDB Configuration]

I then shut down Windows Firewall in the VM

[image: Windows Firewall Disabled]

Added the ports to NSG, and applied the rule for the NIC and the SubNetwork.

[image: NSG Configuration]

Enabled IP Forwarding

[image: IP Forwarding]

Lastly, I added a NAT rule to the Load Balancer

[image: Load Balancer NAT Config]

None of this worked and I could not install RavenDB because the ports are not acessible. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it could be your issue, I had a similar issue with a Load Balancer where my VM didn't have internet connectivity.

Do you have internet inside this VM?
What kind of SKU are you using for your load balancer?

Standard Load Balancer and Standard Public IP introduce new abilities and different behaviors to outbound connectivity. They are not the same as Basic SKUs. If you want outbound connectivity when working with Standard SKUs, you must explicitly define it either with Standard Public IP addresses or Standard public Load Balancer.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections

Outbound connectivity, for vnets with a standard* SKU load balancer does not exist automatically: the VMs requiring outbound access must either be given an external facing IP address, or be put into a backend pool of the load balancer AND the load balancer must have an outbound rule defined for the required outbound traffic on that backend pool (even if the rule merely accepts the default options).

- For a basic SKU load balancer this isn't necessary.

Comment: It's basic SKU and I have internet on VM. I have just one VM, do I need to have a load balancer? Can I remove it?

Comment: If I understood well you want to install RavenDB inside a VM behind a load balancer, right? By default VNET and LoadBalancer has NSG allowed, go to Network Watcher and run some test (Flow IP, Next Hop and Capture Package). I would say it is missing something in your Load Balancer, just in case, remove it and try to install without a LB.